# Mounting a remote filesystem on Windows 10 using Bash

Tags: windows, bash, windows-10, ssh

Now, that windows 10 is out I started wondering about something. Unix based systems have the possibility to mount remote filesystems using ssh. In a recent article I've read that Windows 10 Has finally gotten itself ssh support.

I was wondering if the mounting option is also included in this SSH integration and if any of you could tell me more about this and how to use this feature.

#### Update - April 5, 2016

The Windows 10 Bash update (Linux subsystem) is now in Beta. I am wondering if the situation has changed. Can we now mount remote filesystems from Windows 10?

#### Update - August 5, 2016

The Windows 10 anniversary update has been released. Has anyone got any info about this question?

#### Update - October 10, 2016

A few more months have passed. Lots of visitors have viewed this question but no answer has come up. I am happily using `win-sshfs` but would really appreciate a windows native method to mount remote filesystems.

#### Update - November 14, 2017

The software has become a little more stable. More people have had a chance to experiment with it and a few Windows Updates have come and gone. Still, I haven't found a way to mount remote filesystems natively in Windows 10. Is there anyone that has?

Comment: You are still limited to the file systems Windows can recognize though.

Comment: Actually SFTP wouldn't need you to understand the underlying file system - I've done something similar with third party tools. Its not at all different from how FTP would be treated in theory

Comment: [offtopic] The UNIXisation of Windows... The horrors!

Comment: Is this different now that WSL supports FUSE?

Answer (score 9):

[SFTP Net Drive](https://www.nsoftware.com/sftp/drive/) is a brilliant free solution. Some features are pro only but most features you could need for home/small business use are supported.

Perhaps off-topic:
If the "remote" file system is local and is on Linux anyway, you can use [Samba](https://www.samba.org/) to mount Linux shares on Windows. Samba is very powerful and versatile but it is not too much of a hazzle to setup a few home shares.

My personal experience with Dokan based programs in Windows 10 is that they don't work at all (or won't install).

Comment: I would have rather not given you the bounty because you did not answer my question. But since there is no better alternative, I have no other choice.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry to bring the sad news. Have been looking for a better alternative for quite some time myself. Perhaps it's not far away with bash coming to Windows and all

Comment: update [SFTP net drive link](http://www.sftpnetdrive.com/), free for personal usage. 

requires name/email

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for writing this as an answer, but I have not reached 50 rep yet to comment.
I have successfully mounted ssh filesystem on windows 8 using cygwin about a year ago and even doing the mount as a system service (was going crazy with windows 8 permissions in samba).
So, as long as you have a good implementation of ssh (openssh?) on your system you should be able to mount a ssh filesystem..

However, Ican not research this, since I refuse to install win10 (I care about my integrity) and even thinking about abandoning Linux for BSD (pulse audio, systemd).

So, you could achive this with openssh in cygwin, using cygwin to set up a system service or you might research if there is a ssh client / server for the windows bash shell.

However, it looks like Microsoft is working on this..
Take a look at this blog post:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/06/03/looking-forward-microsoft-support-for-secure-shell-ssh/

Comment: You're close to having the rep to comment, but posting commentary as an answer will attract downvotes that will reduce your rep.

Comment: Might be so.however I think I provide useful information. Even if I'd prefer to do this as a comment I really felt I wanted to help. You might delete my comment if you find it inappropriate.

Answer (score 3):

[Win-sshfs](https://github.com/dimov-cz/win-sshfs) is able to mount remote file systems using SSH on Windows. It is using [Dokany](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany) that is fork of Dokan and also compatible with Windows 10. I am using it myself on windows 10.

Comment: This is the software I am using right now. I just hoped that windows 10 would get its own mount feature.

Comment: Works in October 2017

Answer (score 0):

I have been on the Windows Evaluation, and had not heard of that ability. Dokan is an option, but I have not tried it on Windows 10.

https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/

Answer (score -1):

[RaiDrive](https://www.raidrive.com/) is a fantastic, free alternative that provides the same SFTP drive mounting functionality as SFTP Net Drive.  I wanted to provide this as alternative because I have found small instabilities in SFTP Net Drive with my use over several years (even after the initial development phase).  However, RaiDrive has been stable through multiple updates over the 6+ month period that I have used it.

Answer (score -2):

I found a native work around for the missing sshfs.  In my case I wanted to edit files for which normally I would use sshfs.  I found a work around in the mean time using rsync incremental update and a few bash files.  There's a full description of it here:

http://collaboradev.com/2016/08/26/windows-10-bash-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: Please don't promote your own blog without disclosure, and in addition, please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: [What signifies "Good" self promotion? (or: Self Promotion Part Infinity)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)

Comment: "Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, **you must disclose your affiliation in your answers**. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons."